# Why does my python program doesn't change the string value to another string value?

Tags: python, string, integer

the program is designed to change the numbers from integers to words and vice versa. When I put in the numbers written in words (three, four etc), it does not change them to integers and I do not udnerstand why.

```
number = input("Numbers: (max five):\n")
number = str(number)

if number.isalnum():
    is_number = True
else:
    is_number = False

characters = len(number)
words = len(number.split())

if is_number:
    one = number.replace("1", "one")
    two = one.replace("2", "two")
    three = two.replace("3", "three")
    four = three.replace("4", "four")
    five = four.replace("4", "five")
    six = five.replace("6", "six")
    seven = six.replace("7", "seven")
    eight = seven.replace("8", "eight")
    nine = eight.replace("9", "nine")
else:
    one = number.replace("one", "1")
    two = one.replace("two", "2")
    three = two.replace("three", "3")
    four = three.replace("four", "4")
    five = four.replace("five", "5")
    six = five.replace("six", "6")
    seven = six.replace("seven", "7")
    eight = seven.replace("eight", "8")
    nine = eight.replace("nine", "9")
    nine = nine.replace(" ", "")

if words > 5 or characters > 5:
    print("Too many numbers given")
else:
    print(nine)
```

Comment: Did you read the doc for the `isalnum` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
if words > 5 or (is_number and characters > 5):
    print("Too many numbers given")
else:
    print(nine)
```

Also I think you should exit the program early if you don't plan on giving users output, instead of computing it and returning a `"Too many numbers given"`.